# Implementation of reactive file write from InputStream

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming

I want to implement reactive write to file. 
In low level, it uses NIO and Futures.
After reading [this section](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_push_model)
I created this code but maybe there's more clean or less code solution.

Thanks.

```
public class LocalImageService implements IImageService {
    private String imageDir = "/tmp";

@Override
public Mono<String> storeImage(@NonNull InputStream imageStream, @NonNull String ext) {
    val processor = new ImageProcessor();
    processor.fileName = UUID.randomUUID() + "." + ext;
    val targetFile = new File(imageDir, processor.fileName);

    final Flux<CompletableFuture<Integer>> bridge = Flux.push(sink -> {
        try {
            processor.sink = sink;
            processor.inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(imageStream);
            processor.fileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(targetFile.toPath(),
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);
            processor.processNextChunk();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            processor.onError(new RuntimeException("Can not write image file: " + processor.fileName, e));
        }
    });
    return bridge.flatMap(Mono::fromFuture)
        .reduce(0, (acc, num) -> {
            processor.buffer.compact();
            processor.processNextChunk();
            return acc + num;
        })
        .then(Mono.just(targetFile.getPath()));
}

private static final class ImageProcessor {
    int position = 0;
    ReadableByteChannel inputChannel;
    AsynchronousFileChannel fileChannel;
    FluxSink<CompletableFuture<Integer>> sink;
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4096);
    String fileName;

    void onComplete() {
        closeStreams();
        if (null != sink) {
            sink.complete();
        }
    }

    private void closeStreams() {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputChannel);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileChannel);
    }

    void onError(Throwable e) {
        closeStreams();
        if (null != sink) {
            sink.error(e);
        }
    }

    void processNextChunk() {
        try {
            int receivedBytes;
            if ((receivedBytes = inputChannel.read(buffer)) >= 0 || buffer.position() > 0) {
                buffer.flip();
                val lastWrite = fileChannel.write(buffer, position);
                position += receivedBytes;
                if (lastWrite != null) {
                    sink.next(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                        try {
                            return lastWrite.get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                            onError(new RuntimeException("Can not write image file: " + fileName, e));
                            return -1;
                        }
                    }));
                }
            } else {
                onComplete();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            onError(new RuntimeException("Can not write image file: " + fileName, e));
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: would this help? https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking